# Proof $f=x^2y^5+x^3+xy^2+y^2+x-1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

> I need to show that 
>   $$f=x^2y^5+x^3+xy^2+y^2+x-1$$
>   is irreducible in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$.

What I did so far is "watching" $f$ as a polynomial in $\Bbb{C}[x]$ with coefficients in $\Bbb{C}[y]$ (since $A[x][y]\simeq A[x,y]$, where $A$ is a ring), so we can rewrite $f$ as

$$f=a_3(y)x^3+a_2(y)x^2+a_1(y)x+a_0(y)$$
where 
$$a_3(y)=1,\ a_2(y)=y^5,\ a_1(y)=y^2+1,\ a_0(y)=y^2-1.$$

So, since $\deg(f)=3$, to show $f$ is irreducible, it is sufficient to show that $f$ has no roots in $\Bbb{C}[y]$. Furthermore, if $f$ has any roots, they must divide the independent term $a_0(y)=y^2-1$. Then the possible roots are

$$\ \pm(y+1),\ \pm(y-1),\ \pm(y^2-1).$$

Now I should plug those values on $f$ and check that none of them are roots of $f$, but I'm not sure if this is the right way to conclude that. I did

$$f(y+1)=y^7+2y^6+2y^3+5y^2+4y+1.$$

Can I conclude then that $f(y+1)\neq 0$ and discard $y+1$ as a possible root of $f$? I'm still having some difficulties regarding polynomials in multiple variables, so excuse me if this is a naive question. Any help would be appreciate!

Comment: $8x^3-1$ is reducible in $\mathbb{Z}$ but has no root in $\mathbb{Z}$. And the argument with the roots dividing $a_0(y)$ need not be true also! So no the proof is not correct!

Comment: But the polynomial is monic here viewed as a polynomial of $x$ over the ring $\mathbb{C}[y]$ in this case my above objections are not there and your proof is correct!

Comment: @baharampuri But that is because $8x^3-1$ is not monic, so we cannot proceed with the roots dividing $a_0(y)$. But my polynomial is monic, so...

Comment: right I just realized that after I wrote the comment.

Comment: So is it okay then to conclude that $f$ is irreducible? (checking the rest of the possible roots, obviously)

Comment: It is okay because of the fact that $\Bbb{C}[y]$ is integrally closed and an UFD. A monic polynomial with coefficients in $\Bbb{C}[y]$ has monic irreducible factors.

Comment: How can you conclude that f(y+1) is not zero

Comment: @ManolisLyviakis Identically 0...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you noticed 
$$f=x^3+a_2(y)x^2+a_1(y)x+a_0(y)\in\mathbb C(y)[x],$$
where 
$$a_2(y)=y^5,\ a_1(y)=y^2+1,\ a_0(y)=y^2-1.$$
Suppose that $f$ is reducible and find $u(y)\in\mathbb C[y]$ such that $f(u(y))=0$. So $$u^3(y)+y^5u^2(y)+(y^2+1)u(y)+y^2-1=0.$$ Then $u(y)\mid y^2-1$, so $\deg u(y)\le2$. But in this case $\deg y^5u^2(y)>\deg u^3(y)$, $\deg y^5u^2(y)>\deg (y^2+1)u(y)$, and $\deg y^5u^2(y)>\deg (y^2-1)$, so the above equality is not possible.

Comment: @A.Jiménez Let me tell you the following: "if a polynomial of degree $3$ is reducible then it has a root" is valid over *fields*. Then you have to view $f$ as a polynomial in $\mathbb C(y)[x]$, so the root is from $\mathbb C(y)$, that is, a rational fraction. But since the leading coefficient of $f$ is $1$ you may assume that the root is in fact a polynomial from $\mathbb C[y]$ (and I also did this).

Comment: It's kind of confusing viewing $f$ as a polynomial in $\Bbb{C}(y)[x]$, since now the coefficients of $f$ are also polynomials on the variable $y$. And I think I can see the relations between the degrees you stated above, but how is it that the equality is not possible? I'd like to understand your proof correctly, but is it then something wrong qith the path I took?

Comment: I mean, is it not sufficient to show that $f$ is not identically zero for every possible factor dividing $y^2-1$?

Comment: I can't see any confusion to view the polynomial with coefficients from $\mathbb C(y)$. Moreover, as I've already pointed out this is the correct way.

Comment: If you have a polynomial relation which is $0$ then you have to cancel all the monomials in order to get $0$. But the leading monomial of $y^5u^2(y)$ can't be cancelled for degree reasons.

Comment: My mistake. I didn't see the last part of your first comment. Simpler and clearer now. Thanks :)